# Issue with getting input from C++

Tags: c++, input, output

The code I'm using is this:

```
string input;
cout<<"First line"<<endl;
cin>>input;
cout<<"second line: "<< input << endl;
getline(cin, input);
cout<<"third line: "<< input << endl;
```

However, when I input 54 say the output is this:

```
First line
>56
second line: 56
third line:
```

and the program terminates without even asking for another input. This is weird as the following does work as expected:

```
string input;
cout<<"First line"<<endl;
getline(cin, input);
cout<<"second line: "<< input << endl;
getline(cin, input);
cout<<"third line: "<< input << endl;
```

i.e. input & output is:

```
First line
>56
second line: 56
>45
third line: 45
```

Comment: `getline()` consumes `\n`, `cin >>` does not.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567291/why-does-stdgetline-skip-input-after-a-formatted-extraction

Comment: To read whole lines use `std::getline()`, the extraction operator `<<` just reads single space delimited fields from the input

Answer (score 0):

I believe the first example does not prompt for additional input because the >> operator does not consume the whitespace at the end of your first input (the newline character) and then the subsequent `getline()` call consumes that newline character and stops looking for more input.

If my hypothesis holds, then I think two calls to `getline()` ought to return first an empty string and then it will prompt for input.

Comment: You believe? or are you sure?

Comment: I am not sure about anything. Hell, I'm not sure that computing is a deterministic process, but rather a very accurate heuristic.

Comment: As from my experience it's a pretty deterministic and exact science. And hypothesis for smaller pieces of code can always be proven easily with unit test cases (which are our equivalents of physical experimenting)

Answer (score 0):

The new line character remains in the stream after doing the `cin>>input`, which means that `getline` returns an empty string. You can try doing `cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max())` or just `cin.ignore()` before the call to `getline`.